# Setting up sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark

I am working on setting up sparklyr utilizing R but I keep getting an error message.  I essentially have this type in:

```
install.packages("sparklyr")
library(sparklyr)
spark_install(version = "2.1.0")


sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
```

However when I get to create my spark connect I am receiving the following error message:

- Using Spark: 2.1.0
  Error in if (a[k] > b[k]) return(1) else if (a[k] < b[k]) return(-1L) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
  In addition: Warning messages:
  1: running command '"C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\java.exe" -version' had status 2 
  2: In compareVersion(parsedVersion, "1.7") : NAs introduced by coercion

Any thoughts?

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate that error, it looks like it's getting thrown deep in the logic somewhere... the warning might be a hint, though (or might be a red herring). It looks like it's checking for java 1.7... what do you get if you open command prompt and run `java -version`?

Comment: Thanks, I restarted and its working now!